# Why can't I enter the Java Standard Library when debugging in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, debugging

I've been using VS Code for quite some time, on a number of machines. Never had an issue with stepping into functions and seeing the standard library if I so choose. However, on my new laptop I can't do that. When debugging all the steps into it still populate in the call stack, but they're grayed out and they don't populate in new tabs and they can't be clicked on. I'm not sure where to go from here.
[Screenshot of VS Code debugger with grayed out call stack][image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKxgQ.png)

Comment: You possible have a (Java 8 or earlier) JRE installation that doesn't include the source code ZIP for the Java SE libraries.  Install a JDK instead.

Comment: @StephenC java -version in terminal shows "openjdk version '19.0.2' 2023-01-17" It seems I have an updated JDK. My code also compiles and can run just fine, but I still can't step into the standard library and view the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Comment by StephenC lead me to checking into the version of Java I was running. This laptop had openjdk 19 on it, which I thought would be enough, as I checked and it seemed updated. I uninstalled the openjdk packages & reinstalled Java JDK 20 from the Oracle site and now I can step into the standard library like I want.

If you're having the same issue I was, run java -version and check to see if you have "java version#" installed, or if you have "openjdk version#" installed. They offer different levels of debugging.